# jquery functions - multiple inputs / 1 function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following 3 actions that essentially check a radio button when a label is clicked.  is there a way to write these as one function as opposed to 3 individual ones?

```
$("input[name='customOrder-qty']").on('click', function() {
    $('#qtyPackage-custom').prop('checked', true);  
 });

$("input[name='customOrder-price']").on('click', function() {
    $('#qtyPackage-custom').prop('checked', true);  
 });

$("input[name='customOrder-name']").on('click', function() {
    $('#qtyPackage-custom').prop('checked', true);  
 });
```

thank you

Comment: Remember, jQuery selectors are just like CSS selectors.

Comment: I would go with Sushanth's answer below. The "starts with" selector that he demonstrates is very useful since all your input name values start with `customOrder-`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few ways you can do it:

One is to combine your selectors for the event so that you would have

```
$("input[name='customOrder-qty'], input[name='customOrder-price'], input[name='customOrder-name']").on('click', function() {
    $('#qtyPackage-custom').prop('checked', true);
});
```

The other is to define the bound code as an actual function, and call the function from each event binding

```
$("input[name='customOrder-qty']").on('click', doStuff);

$("input[name='customOrder-price']").on('click', doStuff);

$("input[name='customOrder-name']").on('click', doStuff);

function doStuff()
{
    $('#qtyPackage-custom').prop('checked', true);
}
```

Or you can combine both methods to have the following

```
$("input[name='customOrder-qty'], input[name='customOrder-price'], input[name='customOrder-name']").on('click', doStuff);

function doStuff()
{
    $('#qtyPackage-custom').prop('checked', true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**use selectors separated by commas**

```
$("input[name='customOrder-qty'], input[name='customOrder-price'] 
                  ,input[name='customOrder-name'] ").on('click', function() { 
      $('#qtyPackage-custom').prop('checked', true);
});
```

or better use   Attribute contains or starts with selector

```
$("input[name*='customOrder']").on('click', function() { 
      $('#qtyPackage-custom').prop('checked', true);
});
```

[contains selector - `*`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

[starts with       - `^`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

Add a common class name to each of the inputs. This makes it a lot easier to scale the logic.

**HTML**

```
<input class="myClass" />
```

**JS**

```
$(".myClass").on('click', function() { $('#qtyPackage-custom').prop('checked', true);});
```